# what does breaking ties mean in Order function in R?

Tags: r

In the description for order{base} function:

> order returns a permutation which rearranges its first argument into ascending or descending order, breaking ties by further arguments.

I understand that x[order(x)] returns the same result as sort(x),but i don't understand what passing further arguments do,like in the first example in documentation:

```
>(ii <- order(x <- c(1,1,3:1,1:4,3), y <- c(9,9:1), z <- c(2,1:9)))
 [1]  6  5  2  1  7  4 10  8  3  9
>rbind(x, y, z)[,ii] # shows the reordering (ties via 2nd & 3rd arg)
```

Comment: Yes, thats it ! Thanks :)

Comment: I hope you voted to close your question.